# How should I start making a FCFS Scheduling Program in C or C++?

Tags: c, algorithm, scheduling, simulator

I am stuck on my current assignment, mainly because I'm just not very proficient in C after not using for quite a while.

We need to make a FCFS (First Come First Serve) Scheduling Algorithm Simulator that simply goes through and goes through all of the time events that would take place for each process and print out when they completed their process and their turnaround time.

I get how the process works, but implementing it into a C or C++ program is stumping me and I don't even know where to begin.

We will be getting our input from stdin and it will be in this format:

First line: (# of cpus) (# of processes) (quantum size)

Process line: (ID) (Priority) (time of submission) (cpu time required) (compute time before I/O is needed) (I/O time for each compute)

More Process Lines needed based on how many processes are defined from the first line.

example input may be:

1 1 10

1 1 0 20 5 50

Long story short, can anyone point me to some resources that will help or sample source that include a possibility of multiple CPUs. Or if you guys can even help me get started I would really really appreciate it. I'm not asking for you to make the whole thing, just help get me started so I will know where to go from there.

Thanks!

edit:

Here is what I've got so far. It's extremely rudimentary, but as of now I'm just trying to get this done and like I said, I'm extremely rusty with C (not that I was proficient with it anyways):

```
int main()
{
    //process *  proc = (process *)malloc(100*sizeof(process));
    process proc[25];
    CPU cp[4];
    int count = 0;
    //int * input = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
    int input = 0;
    int cpus = 0;
    int processes = 0;
    int quantum = 0;
    int processLoop = 0;
    int x = 0;

    int id = 0;
    int pri = 0;
    int sub = 0;
    int cptime = 0;
    int compute = 0;
    int itime = 0;
    int complete = 0;


    while(1 == scanf("%d", &input))
    {
            if(count < 0)
                    break;
            if(count == 0)
            {
                    cpus = input;
            }
            else if(count == 1)
            {
                    processes = input;
            }
            else if(count == 2)
            {
                    quantum = input;
            }
            else
            {
                    if(count == 3)
                    {
                            proc[processLoop].ID = input;
                    }
                    else if(count == 4)
                    {
                            proc[processLoop].Priority = input;
                    }
                    else if(count == 5)
                    {
                            proc[processLoop].subTime = input;
                    }
                    else if(count == 6)
                    {
                            proc[processLoop].cpuTime = input;
                    }
                    else if(count == 7)
                    {
                            proc[processLoop].computeTime = input;
                    }
                    else if(count == 8)
                    {
                            proc[processLoop].ioTime = input;
                            proc[processLoop].isCompleted = 0;
                            processLoop++;
                            if(processLoop == processes)
                            {
                                    count = -1;         //Leaves possibility for multiple simulations in one run
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    count = 2;          //Repeats if multiple processes are detected
                            }
                    }
            }
            count++;

    }

    for(x = 0; x < cpus; x++)
    {
            cpu[x].idle = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Yeah, super primitive and not efficient, but it reads all the numbers and ends at either EOF or when anything not a digit comes it's way. Also a negative number. The reason I made proc an array of 25 is because that is the limit our instructor said the number will go up too. And with CPUs, he said a max of four will be used, so I just made an array, mainly because I'm terrible with pointers.

Now that I have the data into my array(s), I need to sort through my proc array by subTime and get started with the actual calculations. How bad will this part be, especially with my lousy set up?

Comment: If there is another language you are proficient in, start w/ that.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you need a priority for a FCFS scheduling?

Comment: I'm really practicing perl right now, but I need to do this in either c or c++ and I should try and get better with these anyways to better myself in the future. And I am not really sure why a priority is needed because in all of my instructors examples they are just sequential.

Comment: A priority is likely needed because next week's homework will probably be to modify the program to do something with priorities, and it's an advantage to not have the input format change for different scheduling strategies.

Comment: FCFS scheduling can still use priority levels. E.g. jobs at the same priority complete FCFS, but a higher priority can preempt lower priority. This is analogous to prioritized round-robin.

Answer (score 3):

Action plan for you to achieve your goal:

1. Define data structures for process and CPU
2. Scan all inputs. Initialize all data structures.
3. Develop code for single CPU. Verify if it works correctly
4. Modify the code for multiple CPU. Verify if it works

**Step 1:**

Define a data structure for Process. For C you can use struct like this: (for C++ use class)

```
typedef struct process
 {
       int ID;
       int Priority;
       int time_of_submission;
       int cpu_time_required;
       int compute_time_before_IO;
       int IO_time_per_compute;
       int isCompleted; // if 1 means its complete. at start, its value is 0
 }process;
```

For CPUs, maintain an array which can tell you id its idle or assigned some process.

```
typedef struct CPU
 {
       int idle;     // if set to 1, then its idle. 
                     // If set to 0, then its working on a process
       process *next; // points to the process that CPU is executing
                      // points to null if CPU is idle.
 }CPU;
```

**Step 2:**

Scan all inputs using [scanf](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=564), populate an array of '`process`' for all inputs processes. To make your work easy, sort the array of '`process`' based on the fields that decide the scheduling as per FCFS. (eg. time_of_submission, cpu time required, Priority.. i am leaving it to you for other fields)

Initialize array of '`CPU`'.

**Step 3:**
Develop code for single CPU. Verify if it works correctly.

I think you are having issue with the multiple CPU scenario. So get that multiple CPU notion out of consideration for time being. Write down the logic for single CPU on paper. Create pseudo code. Then create a C (or C++) code out of it. Whenever stuck at syntax, google it on how to do that and move ahead.

**Step 4:** 
Modify the code for multiple CPU. Verify if it works

Think about what will happen with mutiple CPU.

```
Loop over all CPUs. 
    For CPU[i], check its status 

    if its idle
         assign it a process..similar logic as for single CPU case (step 3)
    if its not idle
         if its corresponding process is finished, set status of CPU to idle.
```

Once you are done here, you can modify this to have priority of process to be considered.

Comment: wow this is great. I appreciate all the time you put into this! I'll get started with the advice you gave me and see how it goes!

Comment: So I am having some trouble with the input process. Since we need to leave the possibility that there will be more than 1 simulation going on, I'm not sure how to limit that each number goes where it should. I am using a while loop to keep asking input until EOF or anything but a digit in put in: `while(1 == scanf("%d", %input))` and I made a count so that the first three numbers found are put into the variables: cpus, processes, and quantums. So the rest of the input is based on how many processes there are (meaning I will need 6 more numbers for each process). How should do this process?

Comment: after you read first line, you know that the rest stuff is about process details. ID of a process cannot be negative. So when user provides negative value for ID, get out of the while loop using break statement of C.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//fcfs algorithm in c++

//Here is the simple example involving 3 process;
//All process are assumed to be arrived at same time=0 seconds

int main()
{
    //arrival time of each proces=0;
    //all arive at same time
    //arrival time is assumed to be same
    int process[10]={1,2,3};
    int bt[10]={10,5,8};
    int wt[10];
    int tt[10];
    wt[0]=0;
    //waiting time of each process;

    for(int i=1;i<3;i++){
        wt[i]=bt[i-1]+wt[i-1];

    }
    //turnaround time calculation for each processs
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        tt[i]=wt[i]+bt[i];

    }
    float awt=0;//average waiting time
    float att=0;//average turnaround time;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        awt=awt+wt[i];
        att=att+tt[i];

    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout<<"process"<<i+1<<"--->"<<" "<<bt[i]<<" "<<wt[i]<<" "<<tt[i]<<endl;


    }
    cout<<"Awerage waiting time"<<awt/3<<endl;
    cout<<"average turnaround time"<<att/3<<endl;




}
```

Comment: This is the simple explanation of fcfs algorithm in c++. You can do it for multiple process and take input burst time accordingly.